# How to fix Gradle in android studio build issue showing exceptions of classpath

Tags: java, android, gradle

I downloaded Android Studio and tried to import a project but the Exception of classpath showed up. The Exceptions are:

> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode.
>
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
>
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

Now the solutions I have already tried but failed are.

1. Already tried to fix the classPath to my Gradle version and (Invalidate and restart)
2. Tried to Delete the Gradle files and restart the building of Gradle files by regenerating it.
3. And tried to also set the min SDK to what my new Project generates.

But I am still now able to clear that issue and it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

ust disable gradle offline mode and try, will work fine.

To disable offline mode in Android Studio 3.6.1

1. Click on gradle window (on right side of studio)
2. Select the project
3. Click Toggle Offline Mode button (disable here)  [image: check image here]

Comment: Hello. I tried and was not able to do it. However, found a solution. Here it is. I deleted the Gradle caches in .gradle file and tried building it again and was successful but thanks